# How can I make sure that I have the correct root certificate in my browser?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

How can I make sure that the root certificate in my browser (say VeriSign) is correct and is what it actually should be?

I found that the root certificate information is available [here](https://www.symantec.com/theme/roots). But what if the site is compromised as well and the fingerprint is modified in a way to match the compromised root certificate? So all the certificates that are signed by root CA could be compromised too.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote? I totally showed what I've looked so far and the question is clear too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point, you need to trust someone. Whether this is your browser maintainer who embedded the certificate or the website of the certificate authority that provides the root certificate.

For sure, if your trusted source is compromised, their is a risk of you being tricked.